# Maximizing any window leaves a vertical bar uncovered

Tags: ubuntu, x11

The vertical bar is in the left and it's much wider than and unrelated to the Unity side bar. It's as if the desktop area does not include a left vertical bar, but only for maximized windows: (parts of) other, unmaximized, windows can access (occupy) that area and are indeed thus visible (in that area) when the window is maximized. I switched to metacity and I got the same problem. I also restarted Unity, without logging out and back in.

I need to know the reason. I know a reboot will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This line in a script I tested is the culprit: `xprop -id <any window> -f _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL 32c -set _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL '200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0'`. Replacing `200` with `0` solved the problem. (What would be a general way to undo all such `xprop` changes anyway?)

Somebody please explain why it affects all windows even though I used it only for one specific window. Some explanation as to what this line was supposed to do wouldn't be bad. If there is no answer in a while, I'll "accept" mine.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the reverse problem, the maximized windows took up the whole screen, while I need to have a margin on the left and at the bottom.

Doing some research I found that `xprop` and [`_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#NETWMSTRUTPARTIAL) is a way to create desktop margins.

I associate my strut with `gkrellm` window, to create the left margin, set `left` with the width of the margin:

```bsh
left=77
```

then I specify the initial and final y of the left margin:

```bsh
left_start_y=0
left_end_y=823
```

for convenience I also associate the margin at the bottom with `gkrellm` window, first, set the bottom margin height:

```bsh
bottom=35
```

and the initial and final x:

```bsh
bottom_start_x=0
bottom_end_x=1919
```

the other values ​​all to 0

```bsh
xprop -name gkrellm -f _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL 32c -set _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL \
     "$left, $right, $top, $bottom, $left_start_y, $left_end_y, $right_start_y, $right_end_y, $top_start_x, $bottom_end_x"
```